# Запрет на выдачу данных по несуществующей странице в ListView Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, listview

Есть простой listView.

```
 public function actionGetDataNextPage()
    {
        $modelSearch = new PostSearch();
        $dataProvider = $modelSearch->search($params);
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 4;

        return ListViewAircraft::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'itemView' => '_item',
            'itemOptions' => ['tag' => false],
            'layout' => '<div class="grid">{items}</div>',
            'summary' => false,
            'pager' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

Нужно что б по ссылке

```
http://site.local/controller/get-data-next-page?page=2
```

при несуществующей странице не выдавать данные

То есть, если пользователь вручную ввел

```
page=N
```

то выводить данные только в том случае если они действительно существуют на данной странице.

Сейчас при любом N больше максимального колличества страниц приводит к выводу с последней странице, а нужно вернуть 404

Comment: там где вы получаете дата провайдер, получите количество страниц, если текущая страница больше максимальной то делайте то что вам надо

Comment: дело в том что я не могу найти как этот запрос обработать и вернуть 404, все делает yii2

Comment: приведите в вашем вопросе код контроллера

Comment: вот как то так.

Answer (score 0):

Это очень просто

```
$dataProvider->getModels();

if ($dataProvider->pagination->getPageCount() < Yii::$app->getRequest()->get('page')) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not found page!');
}
```

Только нужно учесть, что пока не вызовите `$dataProvider->getModels()` (обычно это делает виджет например GridView) то `$dataProvider->pagination->getPageCount()` не даст результата так как провайдер до этого момента ещё ничего не знает о ваших данных